# python pickle save dictionary, a list of tuples is lost

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I'm new to Python. I tried to save my results but failed. Could anyone help me to correct my code?

```
parameter = k ##(k is an number)
L = [(1,matrix1), (2,matrix2), (2,matrix2),...]
```

First I make a dictionary to put my result

```
My_dict = {'parameter':k, 'my_list': L}
```

I used the following code to save and read:

```
import pickle
output = open('result.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(My_dict, output, -1)
output.close()
```

(I check my dictionary here and everything is correct till now)

But when I try to read my data:

```
pkl_file = open('result.pkl', 'rb')
res = pickle.load(pkl_file)
pprint.pprint(res)
```

I found my L is empty as shown below:

```
'parameter': k,
'L': []
```

Where part of my code is wrong? Can any one help, please?

Comment: Your first line of code has a typo (the last colon is inside the quotes) but is it like that in your code or was it a transcription error? EDIT fixed now

Comment: Sorry, that typo is correct now. No error information shows when I run my code. The empty L is the only problem.

Comment: Thank you for updating, Rosy, but that first line will still throw a SyntaxError because you're leaving the value of 'my_list' empty and then including a list with no key after it.

Comment: Remove the comma separating the colon and the variable L

Comment: Thanks, removed. But that's my typo here not my problem.

Comment: Did you try to use `DEFAULT_PROTOCOL` instead of `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` since you passed `-1` to `pickle.dump()`?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem... your code worked fine for me in both Python 2 and 3. What are `matrix1`, `matrix2`, etc?

Comment: Give a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you are using numpy arrays, you should reflect that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that my matrices are numpy arrays. It seems that I shouldn't use the pickle to save the numpy arrays.

Comment: Why not?  Typically you should use the built-in 'dumps'… but pickling still works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are having trouble pickling `numpy` arrays or matrix objects.  They should pickle.  Here I'm using `dill` to pickle them.

```
>>> import dill
>>> n = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> m = numpy.matrix(n)
>>> m
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]])
>>> dill.dumps(n)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_array\nq\x00(cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x01cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x02K\x00\x85q\x03U\x01bq\x04\x87q\x05(K\x01K\x02K\x03\x86q\x06cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x07U\x02i8q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03U\x01<q\x0bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x0cb\x89U0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\rtq\x0eNtq\x0fRq\x10.'
>>> dill.dumps(m)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_array\nq\x00(cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x01cnumpy.matrixlib.defmatrix\nmatrix\nq\x02K\x00\x85q\x03U\x01bq\x04\x87q\x05(K\x01K\x02K\x03\x86q\x06cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x07U\x02i8q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03U\x01<q\x0bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x0cb\x89U0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\rtq\x0e}q\x0fU\x08_getitemq\x10\x89stq\x11Rq\x12.'
```

The preferred approach is to use the `dump` method that comes with the `numpy` object.  You can see from the pickle above, this is essentially what `dill` is doing, but just adds a few small things at the beginning (basically, it also serializes the function to unpickle the array).

```
>>> n.dumps()
'\x80\x02cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x01cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x02K\x00\x85U\x01b\x87Rq\x03(K\x01K\x02K\x03\x86cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x04U\x02i8K\x00K\x01\x87Rq\x05(K\x03U\x01<NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tb\x89U0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00tb.'
>>> m.dumps()
'\x80\x02cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x01cnumpy.matrixlib.defmatrix\nmatrix\nq\x02K\x00\x85U\x01b\x87Rq\x03(K\x01K\x02K\x03\x86cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x04U\x02i8K\x00K\x01\x87Rq\x05(K\x03U\x01<NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tb\x89U0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00tb.'
```

So, if `pickle` itself doesn't work on `numpy` objects directly, you can use `dill`, or you can use the `dump`/`dumps` method on the `numpy` object itself.